# Hide Legend in Chart.js V3.7.1

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to hide the legend of a bar chart. Based on my understanding this should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<body>

<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>

<script>
var xValues = ["X", "Y", "Z"];
var yValues = [55, 49, 44];
var barColors = ["red", "green","blue"];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: barColors,
      data: yValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugings: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
    },
  },
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately it still does show a lengend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in plugins. Change "plugings" to "plugins"

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
    },
  }
```

Other than that it should be correct